# How can I get the IP from arp command in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I've build this command:

```
arp -a | grep <mac here> | grep -P '\((.*?)\)' -o
```

This should return an IP address for a specific mac. The problem is that the IP get's returned but with `()` around them. I need them without the `()`. Any idea how I can fix this?

Currently: `(192.168.187.136)`
Should be `192.168.187.136`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe arp is somewhat deprecated and `ip neighbor` is the proper replacement. Since `ip n` output doesn't have those parenthesis, you also avoid this issue

```
ip n | grep <mac here> | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the 1st and last character using sed:

```
arp -a | grep <mac here> | grep -P '\((.*?)\)' -o | sed 's/^|\(.*\)|$/\1/'
```

Also, on BASH 4.2 and newer:

```
ip=$(arp -a | grep <mac here> | grep -P '\((.*?)\)' -o)
echo "${ip:1:-1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

using sed in one command

```
arp -a | grep <mac here> | grep -P '\((.*?)\)' -o | sed 's/^|\(.*\)|$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `grep -P` :

```
arp -a | grep <mac here> | grep -oP '\(\K[^)]*'
```

`\K` is a PCRE meta-character meaning "drop the string matched so far", so you will check that there's a bracket before your result without outputting it, and the negated class `[^)]` will match up to the next bracket excluded.

You can also fuse both `grep`s if the mac address appears before the IP :

```
arp -a | grep -oP '<mac here>.*\(\K[^)]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ip neighboor` and (posix) awk:

```
ip n | awk -v mac='<mac here>' 'mac{print $1}'
```

or using GNU awk and `arp`:

```
arp -a | awk -F'[()]' -v mac='<mac here>' '$0 ~ mac{print $2}'
```